# Trying to generate mongoid.yml fails b/c no gem exists for specified adapter in database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm, mongoid

I'm trying to generate the mongoid.yml file and receiving the error below. I've deleted database.yml. How can I get around this error?

```
$ rails g mongoid:config            
/Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb:143:in `database_configuration': Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`:
Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"] (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:122:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:324:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-5.0.0.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:338:in `active_record_configured?'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:259:in `disconnect_database'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:97:in `preload'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `serve'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: The Mongoid installation docs should cover completely disabling ActiveRecord.

Comment: @muistooshort Can you point me where they do? I'm not finding it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/mongoid-tutorials/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `config/application.rb` remove the following:

`require 'rails/all'`

with the following:

```
require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
# require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

This disables loading `active_record`.

Then you also need to remove or comment out all occurrences of `config.active_record.*` in all the files under `config` directory, which includes `config/application.rb`, all the environment files located under `config/environments/*`, all the initializers located under `config/initializers/`, etc.

And finally, you also need to remove all the models under `app/models` directory which are based off `ApplicationRecord`.

Comment: I did this and when I try to generate the mongoid.yml file I get the error `$ rails g mongoid:config
/Users/tomcaflisch/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007f9b5947c268> (NoMethodError)
 `

Comment: Updated the response.

Comment: I also had to comment out `Rails.application.config.active_record.*` from `config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb`.

Comment: Is there documentation of the steps you outlined on the mongoid documentation? I did not see anything.

Comment: I am not sure if it outlined on the mongoid documentation. I provided you the info on top of my head. Usually people start the project either with `active_record` or `mongoid`. It is less likely that they switch from `active_record` to `mongoid` or vice versa, which probably explains lack of documentation.

Comment: I'm starting a new project. That's what I don't get. How do you start a new project with mongoid? I just did `$rails new app` then modified my gemfile to include mongoid instead of sqllite.

Comment: If you want to start new project with `mongoid`, which means, you don't want to include `active_record` framework, which is a defacto standard ORM for `rails` and is included by default, then you need to start the project with `rails new --skip-active-record`. For a list of all possible options run `rails new --help`.